# "RVM is not a function" when using rails generators' run command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm writing a rails generators gem to template my rails application setup. However, when this line of code is executed:

```
run  "rvm gemset create #{application_name} && rvm gemset use #{application_name}"
```

"RVM is not a function" error appeared. However it seems that the create command did work:

```
ruby-2.1.0 - #gemset created /home/edward/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@blog
ruby-2.1.0 - #generating blog wrappers.

RVM is not a function, selecting rubies with 'rvm use ...' will not work.

You need to change your terminal emulator preferences to allow login shell.
Sometimes it is required to use `/bin/bash --login` as the command.
Please visit https://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal/ for a example.
```

By the way, I already have the login shell enabled long time ago

[image: my terminal profile preferences]

Comment: The first command before the `&&` works fine, thus the gemset is created. Rails doesn't run the commands in a full login shell, thus the complaint from RVM and the second command will fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Rails does not provide a full login shell, you can solve this issue in one of two ways:

#### 1. Using the RVM Ruby API

This might be an elegant solution, but it likely difficult.
The RVM Ruby API is here: https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm-gem

#### 2. Wrapping your commands with RVM's scripting interface.

By running your commands through RVM like this:

```
run "rvm #{current_ruby} do rvm gemset create #{app_name} --ruby-version"
run "rvm #{current_ruby}@#{app_name} do gem install bundler"
run "rvm #{current_ruby}@#{app_name} do bundle install"
```

Comment: Thank you! using "rvm 2.1.0 do rvm gemset use #{application_name} --create" did it for me!